# Could not connect postman to http://localhost:8020/chat-websocket/

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, postman

I have a chat project with springboot, angular and webSocket. I want to test my app with **POSTMAN**, but it doesn't connect to the server, but a browser connects and works fine.

The errors screen:

[image: websocket postman errors]

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you run your WebSocket server on port 80 instead of 8020?

Comment: @RemyLebeau same prob

Answer (score 0):

Are you using any cookies or tokens for authentication?
If you are using a token add the token in the Authentication header.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful. Set allowed origins to accept any origin as following

```
@Configuration @EnableWebSocket
class WSConfig : WebSocketConfigurer {
    override fun registerWebSocketHandlers(registry:
WebSocketHandlerRegistry) {
        val handler = registry.addHandler(ChatHandler(), "/chat")
        handler.setAllowedOrigins("*")
        handler.withSockJS()
    }
}
```